# Postgres syntax error in IF statement with NOT EXIST statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, syntax-error, case

I want to use `IF` statement in insertion.

```
INSERT INTO <table_name>(<columns>) 
VALUES (IF NOT EXISTS (<exist_statement>) THEN 
               (<first set of values>), 
               (<second set of values>) 
        ELSE 
               (<first set of values>) 
        END IF
);
```

But the following error appears:

```
syntax error at or near "NOT"
LINE 1: ...r_id, role_id, role_type, user_status) VALUES (IF NOT EXISTS...
                                                             ^
```

I tried putting this block of code in the `DO`:

```
DO $$ 
BEGIN
<code_block>
END
$$
```

But the error remains.

Comment: There is no `IF` in the SQL language

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. But I found it in the postgres documentation. Section 43.6 in 14 version

Comment: Not sure which version of the manual you refer to, but that's most likely the section about the PL/pgSQL procedural language you were looking at. The [SQL language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql.html) does not have an `IF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `case`:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name>(<columns>) 
VALUES (CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (<exist_statement>) THEN 
               (<first set of values>), 
               (<second set of values>) 
        ELSE 
               (<fist set of values>) 
        END
);
```